# Como conseguir que me saque en un segundo archivo txt las palabras de 5 letras o mas?

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo que crear un archivo y crearle 5 frases, después se crea un segundo archivo paralelo y solo se le van a copiar las frases que tengan 5 letras o mas. Como podría hacer esto?  he realizado los siguientes metodos pero no hay manera, no se como se haría.

```
public static void combinarFitxer(String directori,String fitxerUno) throws IOException {

    insertarFitxerUno(directori,fitxerUno);


    String RutaOriginal = directori + "\\" + fitxerUno;
    String RutaNueva = directori + "\\" + "Nuevo" + fitxerUno;
    char[] cinco = new char[5];

    BufferedWriter buffWrite = null;
    BufferedReader buffRead = null; 

    File fl = new File(RutaOriginal);
    File f3 = new File(RutaNueva);

    if(!fl.exists()) {
        System.out.println("No existe el archivo!");
        return;
    }

    f3.createNewFile();

    try {
        buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(RutaOriginal)); 
        buffWrite =new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(RutaNueva));

        for (char lineas : cinco) {
            copiar(buffWrite, buffRead);
        }


    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        if(buffWrite != null)
            buffWrite.close();
        if(buffRead != null)
            buffRead.close();
    }
}

private static void copiar(BufferedWriter escribir, BufferedReader leer) throws IOException{ //metodo para copiar los datos de un archivo a otro
    String linea=leer.readLine();

    while(linea!=null){
            escribir.write(linea+"\n");         
            linea=leer.readLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta línea de código en ningún momento la usas de una manera útil:

```java
char[] cinco = new char[5];
```

Es decir, utilizarla solo para iterar, sería de por gusto, debido a que, estarías copiando los mismos datos `5` veces.

> > Como conseguir que me saque en un segundo archivo txt las palabras de 5 letras o mas?

Para saber cuantas letras tiene cada palabra puedes usar el método [length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()).

Entonces solo escribirás en el segundo archivo palabras que tengan más de 5 letras y esto se logra a través de una condicional:

```java
if(linea.length() > 5)
    escribir.write(linea+"\n");
```

El código completo quedaría así:

```java
public static void combinarFitxer(String directori,String fitxerUno) throws IOException 
{

    insertarFitxerUno(directori,fitxerUno);
    String RutaOriginal = directori + "\\" + fitxerUno;
    String RutaNueva = directori + "\\" + "Nuevo" + fitxerUno;
    BufferedWriter buffWrite = null;
    BufferedReader buffRead = null; 
    File fl = new File(RutaOriginal);
    File f3 = new File(RutaNueva);

    if(!fl.exists()) {
        System.out.println("No existe el archivo!");
        return;
    }
    f3.createNewFile();
    try 
    {
        buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(RutaOriginal)); 
        buffWrite =new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(RutaNueva));
        copiar(buffWrite, buffRead);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
    finally 
    {
        if(buffWrite != null)
            buffWrite.close();
        if(buffRead != null)
            buffRead.close();
    }
}

private static void copiar(BufferedWriter escribir, BufferedReader leer) throws IOException
{ 
    String linea=leer.readLine();
    while(linea!=null)
    {
        if(linea.length() > 5)
            escribir.write(linea+"\n");  

        linea=leer.readLine();
    }
}
```

**Nota:** El método `copiar` debería ser `público`, no `private`, debido a que no podrías usarlo en otras clases.

Comment: Ahora mismito lo cambio y lo pongo publico jejeje :) Mira que estaba probando y hize un monton de pruebas y me acerque a eso pero como no funcionaba segui probando y la lie mas jajajaja gracias!!!!! funciona perfectamente!!!!